# Já ocorreu o erro "Pure virtual function called" utilizando o Delphi 2009? Como resolver?

Tags: delphi

Sempre quando estou depurando uma aplicação console pelo Delphi 2009 (utilizando o recurso de "Attach to Process") surge um mensagem de erro na IDE dizendo "**Pure virtual function called**".

Quando clico no OK da mensagem, o Delphi se fecha sozinho.

Como o Delphi se fecha após a mensagem, e o erro ocorre em linhas de código aleatórias, desconfio que o problema não tenha a ver com o programa em si.

Alguem já se deparou com esse problema?
Alguem sabe como resolver?

Comment: Já tentou com outras versões do Delphi ?

Comment: @VictorZanella, aqui na empresa só possuímos licenças para o Delphi 2009.

Comment: Tem todos os updates do 2009 ?

Comment: @VictorZanella, pelo que vi, sim. Ele acusa ter até o Update 3 e 4.

Comment: Esse problema acontece independente da versão do sistema operacional e plataforma (x64, x86)?

Comment: @VictorZanella, esse erro específico só vi ocorrer na configuração atual do PC (Windows 10 x64) depurando uma aplicação x86.

Comment: consegue fazer o teste em um windows 7 x64 ?

Comment: Ainda não. Tentarei numa maquina virtual. O problema é que a licença do Delphi é checada pela internet. Pra fazer esse teste no windows 7, talvez eu tenha que recorrer ao "jeitinho brasileiro"... :(

Comment: Se a licença for pelo AppWave, vai ser tranquilo. Pedi para fazer um teste em outras versões do Windows, pois já tive um problema semelhante apos a instalação de algum pacote no Windows 8.

Comment: Vou tentar. Assim que tiver uma noticia boa ou ruim eu aviso.

Answer (score 0):

- Segundo a Embarcadero esse erro ocorre quando o programa faz uma
  chamada a uma função virtual cujo corpo não pode ser encontrado, por
  conta do objeto estar em um estado inválido devido a VMTs não
  inicializadas, memória corrompida, ponteiros inválidos ou erros de
  alocação ou liberação de memória.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Pure_virtual_function_called_(C%2B%2B)

> Como resolver?

Verifique os pontos apontados e certifique-se que não esteja incorrendo em nenhum deles.

Comment: Eu vi esse link, mas parece não ter a ver com esse meu caso. A aplicação funciona normalmente. Inclusive isso ocorre com qualquer programa que eu depure através do "Attach to process".